# Does `dtruss -p PID` list system calls made before dtruss was run?

Tags: performance

I'm trying to diagnose an intermittently slow command. When I run the command and see it hanging, I press control + t to get the PID, then in another tab, run `diagnose [PID]` - eg, `diagnose 123`. I've defined `diagnose` as a function in my zsh configuration:

```
# See system calls of the process with a given PID
function diagnose() { sudo dtruss -cade -p "$1" 2>&1 | tee /tmp/dtruss_output }
```

Obviously, since I'm reacting when I notice a hang, I run `diagnose` several seconds after the process started. The output lists many system calls, but I wonder whether I'm missing anything important.

Does dtruss list commands retroactively? In other words, does the output of `dtruss -p [PID]` include system calls made by that process before `dtruss` was run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## No

I've just run an experiment to test this. I wrote and ran this Ruby script:

```
puts "going to read foo"
puts File.read('/tmp/foo.txt')

sleep 5
puts "going to read bar"
puts File.read('/tmp/bar.txt')

sleep 5
puts "going to read baz"
puts File.read('/tmp/baz.txt')
```

After it started, I ran `diagnose` on its PID, as described above. I only saw one call to `open`:

```
20309/0x4a7118:     34082      41     34 open("/tmp/baz.txt\0", 0x1000000, 0x1B6)        = 7 0
```